# Find the determinant of the following matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to Find the determinant of the following  matrices using **only** determinant properties:

A = $$ 
 \begin{bmatrix}
   4 & -3 & 5  \\
   5 &  2 & 0   \\ 
   2 & 0 & 4   \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

B = $$ 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
    3 & 2 & -4 & -2 \\  
    2 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
    11 & 8 & -4 & 6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$

C = $$ 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 2 & 3 & -4 \\
    3 & -2 & 1 & 5\\
    -2 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
    8 & -2 & 6 & 4 \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
   $$

I have tried every property of determinants, yet I fail to find the solution the way I want, I definitely know the solution using the rules, but I want to use only the properties like just what happen to the determinant when you swipe rows.

Comment: How are "rules" different than "properties"?  If you can find the determinant using the usual longer formula, how does this not count as finding the determinant using properties?  If the usual formulae aren't allowed, then what explicitly *is* allowed?

Comment: what I mean by rules is, for example, the triangle's rule or rule of Sarrus..etc

Comment: And, where did these exact matrices come from?  Did you make up the numbers, or were they given to you?  At a glance, I see no obvious simplifications that can be made, and indeed for most matrices randomly generated there aren't necessarily easy simplifications that can be made.  I see no reason to believe that finding the determinants the long way wouldn't be the most efficient here.

Comment: And properties such as the fact  if you have a matrix with at least a row or a column full of zeros you have determinant  zero, this link have a great post about it,https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/properties-of-determinants-of-matrices/

Comment: They were given to me by my textbook, and I solved a lot of similar problems, and most of the times the determinant is zero. But these three are very hard to me to solve.

Comment: Well... cheating and looking at the row reduced form, the determinant of the second matrix *is* zero, but it is a rank3 matrix so any dependency would involve all four columns or rows, so if you were able to just pull out of thin air "Oh, look and see that the fourth column is $\frac{34}{25}$ times the first plus $-\frac{12}{25}$ times the second plus $\frac{32}{25}$ times the third column..." I would be shocked.  Having gotten those numbers would have been as much or more trouble than finding the determinant the usual way.

Comment: The other two are full rank and so have nonzero determinant.  The first is particularly easy to check thanks to the zeroes.  You could argue that you could row reduce, using elementary row operations which explicitly don't change the determinant, or only flip the sign of the determinant, in order to make the resulting matrix upper triangular, but this again seems just as much work or more work than finding the determinant the usual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really allowed nothing, only row operations, this is basically doing [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) until you get matrix which has zeroes under the diagonal. But you must in each step also check how the determinant is changed.

For the third determinant [WolframAlpha returns $-30$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%5B%5B4%2C2%2C3%2C-4%5D%2C%5B3%2C-2%2C1%2C5%5D%2C%5B-2%2C0%2C1%2C-3%5D%2C%5B8%2C-2%2C6%2C4%5D%5D).

You could calculate it using row operations:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 4 & 2 & 3 & -4 \\
 3 & -2 & 1 & 5\\
-2 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
 8 & -2 & 6 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 4 & 2 & 3 &-4 \\
 3 &-2 & 1 & 5 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 &-3 \\
 4 &-1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2 & 5 &-10\\
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 &-3 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2 & 5 &-10\\
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 &-4 & 5 & 1 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 &-10\\
 0 &-4 & 5 & 1 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 &15 &-18\\
 0 & 0 &-15& 17 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
 0 & 0 &15 &-18\\
 0 & 0 &-15& 17 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
 0 & 0 &15 &-18\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
(-2)\cdot15=-30$$

But the computations are simpler if you are also allowed to use [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion), column operations and other properties of determinants:
$$2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 2 & 5 &-10\\
 1 &-2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 &-4 & 5 & 1 \\
 0 &-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-2\det\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 5 &-10\\
-4 & 5 & 1 \\
-1 & 5 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-10\det\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 1 &-10\\
-4 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
-10\det\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 3 &-18\\
 0 &-3 & 17 \\
-1 & 1 &-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
10\det\begin{pmatrix}
 3 &-18\\
-3 & 17 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
10\det\begin{pmatrix}
 3 &-18\\
-3 & 17 \\
\end{pmatrix}=10(3\cdot17-3\cdot18)=-30$$

I'll leave the first two determinants for you.